# How to copy data from one character matrix to another under certain conditions in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a matrix `name[n][100]` that stores the names of `n` students (`n` is user input). I also have another matrix `namehst[5][100]` which stores names from `name[n][100]` under some conditions (it stores name of student with highest marks).

```
int subhst[1][5] = {};
if (marks[i][j] > subhst[0][0])
{
  subhst[0][0] = marks[i][j];
  topphysics = i;  // I don't want to use this. 
  idhst[0][0] = marks[i][0];
}
```

I have written the code in such a way that `marks[i][j]` stores the marks of `name[i]`. Instead of using `topphysics=i` and then later `cout<<name[i]`, I want to store the the i-th name in the `namehst` matrix. I tried something like `name[i]=subjhst[0]` then for the next loop `name[i]=subjhst[1]` and so on. But this doesn't work.

Comment: Using fixed-sized buffers to store runtime-determined strings is not exactly a great idea. Is there a reason you're not using `std::string`?

Comment: @Dai I may please be excused for not using the best C++ with std::string... Actually I am more familiar with what I am using. I don't know much about std:string.:

Comment: Learn to use `std::string`, it will save you a lot of headaches. You should also say what exactly doesn't work probably including a full error message.

Comment: `std::string` and `std::vector` are the two things that, if you were to use them in the first place, would have eliminated the need for this question altogether